# ValueError: The truth value of an array

Tags: python

I work on a Python 3.11 program and I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Égalisation\Python Version\Wiener Filter\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    symb = [random.choice(A) for _ in range(nbsymb)]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Égalisation\Python Version\Wiener Filter\main.py", line 14, in <listcomp>
    symb = [random.choice(A) for _ in range(nbsymb)]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\random.py", line 369, in choice
    if not seq:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When I run this simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

nbsymb = 8
M = 16
A = np.arange(-np.sqrt(M)+1, np.sqrt(M), 2)
symb = [random.choice(A) for _ in range(8)]
```

Comment: The code you have in the latest edit doesn't raise any errors for me. Are you sure this is *exactly* what you are running?

Comment: I also don't get any errors running the previous code in your first edit

Comment: +1 to C.Nivs, I don't get any errors. Please include the real code (or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and the full error message with the traceback

Comment: Yes, this is the real and full code !

Comment: can you add the error's full stack trace to the question?

Comment: Oh I see, there's been a change in 3.11 ([CPython commit fixing it](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/9a68ff12c3e647a4f8dd935919ae296593770a6b)). Perhaps C.Nivs is running a different Python version. Always include your Python version, error and other relevant information in the question

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question. I have Python 3.11. How can I fix it then @decorator-factory?

Comment: A workaround could be to replace `random.choice(A)` with `A[random.randrange(A.size)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is due to a [regression in Python 3.11](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100805) which was later fixed. Upgrade to Python >=3.11.2

---

Numpy has its own random stuff, perhaps you should use that instead: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/

---

If for some reason you can't upgrade, choose random elements from a list instead of a `numpy` array:

```py
A = list(np.arange(-np.sqrt(M)+1, np.sqrt(M), 2))
symb = [random.choice(A) for _ in range(nbsymb)]
```